# Question on invariant polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

Consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$ and the the cyclic group of order $14$, $C_{14}= \{1, \sigma,...,\sigma^{13} \}$, act on $p(x)$ by $$\sigma^i . p(x) := p( \epsilon^i x)$$ where $\epsilon$ is the primitive complex $14$:th root of unity.

I am supposed to find all the invariant polynomials, does this mean that I have to find all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(\sigma^i x) = p(x)$ ? Have I understood the question correctly?

Also, what properties does the elements of $C_{14}$ have that we need in this question? As I see we might change $C_{14}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{14}$, is this true?

Attempt to solution:
I want to find all polynomials such that $p(\sigma^i x)=p(x)$. Writing out the two polynomials we have $$p(\sigma^j x)=a_n e^{\frac{i \pi n j}{7}}x^n+ \ldots+ a_1 e^{\frac{i \pi j}{7}}x + a_0$$ $$p(x)=a_nx^n + \ldots+a_1x + a_0$$

In order for these polynomials to be equal, we must have $e^{\frac{i \pi j k}{7}} = 1$ for $k=1,...,n$ ( and this must hold for all $j$). It is easily seen that this only happens if each $k$ is a multiple of $14$, i.e if $k = 14t$, $t \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Hence, the invariant polynomials are those of form $p=a_nx^{14n} + ...+a_1x^{14}+ a_0$

I feel I might have done something wrong, is this correct?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like the first homework problem in a course on Representation theory at Stockholm University, due tomorrow. I won't jump to conclusions, and even if you attend that course, you haven't explicitly asked for solutions, so I guess nothing wrong has occurred here. I can say however, that we apparently have tackled this problem in the same way, if that makes for some reassurance…also, there is a definition of invariant polynomials at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_polynomial

Comment: Also, you have a tiny typo: "does this mean that I have to find all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $p(\sigma^ix)=p(x)$". You mean "$p(\epsilon^ix)=p(x)$"

Comment: Yes, you are right. Are you attending the course also? @A.Sh

Comment: Yup, caught red-handed :)

Comment: Nice, we might study together then :) @A.Sh

Comment: Looks entirely legitimate to me.